# URP Renderer Feature works on mobile?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing a VR project using Universal Render Pipeline.
I'm using the Renderer Feature to use the screen space outline in my project.
It works good on pc, but not works on mobile(android). Also, other custom renderer features won't work.

Tested on unity 2019.3.7f1 and Universal RP 7.1.8, 7.4.1.

Is there a way to make the renderer feature work on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have changed all "Opaque Texture" fields to **true** state in all your UniversalRP assets. Worked for me.

[image]